# Unable to apply and remove disabled property from checkbox on click onf another checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in which I want all the checkboxes to be disabled except the first checkbox in every row. And when first checkbox in any row is clicked, all the checkboxes of that row becomes clickable.

[**DEMO JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/L9NFX/)

Below is the code I am using, please suggest on error and solution.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr td').not('nth-child(2)').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled',true);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked',true))
            $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input[type=checkbox]').removeProp('disabled');
        else
            {
                $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
                $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled',true);
            }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border='1'>

<tr>
<td>Test1</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test2</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test3</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test4</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test5</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test6</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to loop through each td on dom load
so your jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {   
    $("table tr td").not(':nth-child(2)').find("input").prop("disabled", true);       
    $("table tr td").find("input").click(function () {
        if($(this).closest('td').index() == 1){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).closest('tr').find("input").prop("disabled", false);}
            else{
                 $(this).closest('tr').find("input").prop("disabled", true);
                $(this).prop("disabled", false);
                 $(this).closest('tr').find("input").prop("checked", '');
                }
        }

    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/L9NFX/5/)

Comment: This only keeps first checkbox of first row clickable, rest all checkboxes are disabled.

Comment: @Vaibhav: check it now.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, can you also specify me the use of 'closest'

Comment: @Vaibhav:it find the closest element . like i have written
$(this).closest('tr').find("input").prop("disabled", false); 
inside click event of checkbox, then it will find the closest tr, that tr which contain that checkbox.
rest you can read it here
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below jquery :

```
$(function(){
    // disable all checkbox except first one in the row
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)').attr('disabled',true);
        // add class firstCheckbox to identify first checkbox and bind click event
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:first').addClass('firstCheckbox');
    });

    // bind click event to first checkbox and enable / disable other checkboxes
    $('table tr').find('.firstCheckbox').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)').attr('disabled',!$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E6t4L/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `:nth-child` in jquery to selected the element

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   // disable the all check box except first one
    $("table tr td").not(':nth-child(2)').find("input").prop("disabled", true); 

        $("table tr td:nth-child(2)").find("input").click(function () {
        // disabled & enabled based on checkbox click
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input").not(':first').prop("disabled", !this.checked);

    });
});
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L9NFX/4/)